# `npm list` errors: `mainprocess exit code: 1`

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am using `npm list` to generate npm lock file, the command running may cost about 30s. Once running over, the error was thrown. How to work around it

Node.js code snippet:

```
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

execSync(`tnpm list --json --silent --production > ${path.join(baseDir, 'build/tnpm.lock')}`, { maxBuffer: 1024 * 1024 * 1024 })
```

Error snippet:

```
[tnpm] subprocess:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tnpm/node_modules/_npm@6.11.3@npm/bin/npm-cli.js exit code: 1, signal: null
[tnpm] mainprocess exit code: 1
child_process.js:677
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: tnpm list --json --silent --production > build/tnpm.lock
[tnpm] subprocess:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tnpm/node_modules/_npm@6.11.3@npm/bin/npm-cli.js exit code: 1, signal: null
[tnpm] mainprocess exit code: 1

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:637:11)
    at execSync (child_process.js:674:13)
    at Object.<anonymous>
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:736:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:747:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:568:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:801:12)
    at executeUserCode (internal/bootstrap/node.js:526:15)
```

Comment: Is it a typo? `tnpm` or did you mean `npm`?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek `tnpm` is also a package management tool, which wrapped with `npm`, the most difference was the registry, you can regard tnpm as npm.

Comment: Does the command run correctly when you run it directly via terminal?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek reproduced via terminal.

Comment: What does the terminal say? Is the error the same or maybe some more info?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek Yes.
 
[tnpm] subprocess:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/tnpm/node_modules/_npm@6.11.3@npm/bin/npm-cli.js exit code: 1, signal: null
[tnpm] mainprocess exit code: 1

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek I try another project with fewer dependencies, no errors. Maybe due to long-time running?